# python win32 com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147467259), None)

Tags: python, pywin32, autodesk-inventor

I have this code to open an Inventor File Dialog.
It was working a OK yesterday and does not work today.

```
import win32com.client

def TestFileDialog():

    ThisApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Inventor.Application")
    oFileDlg = ThisApp.CreateFileDialog()
    oFileDlg.Filter = "Inventor Files (*.iam;*.ipt) #|*.iam;*.ipt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    oFileDlg.FilterIndex = 1
    oFileDlg.DialogTitle = "Open File Test"
    oFileDlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\logig\\MoldTools"
    oFileDlg.ShowOpen()

TestFileDialog()
```

Running the code on the interactive window of VS 2017 I get the following exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b46d3a85376d> in <module>()
     11     oFileDlg.ShowOpen()
     12 
---> 13 TestFileDialog()
     14 

<ipython-input-1-b46d3a85376d> in TestFileDialog()
      9     oFileDlg.DialogTitle = "Open File Test"
     10     oFileDlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\logig\\MoldTools"
---> 11     oFileDlg.ShowOpen()
     12 
     13 TestFileDialog()

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in ShowOpen(self)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147467259), None)
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

The same code was running no problem yesterday. The directory exists, there are files with those extensions... I am totally lost about what could have changed.
Will appreciate your help.

Comment: After trying for a while, tested the function just now and it works !!!

Comment: Did you find out, what the problem was?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I don't know for certain. I was testing this conversion from VB to Python on Autodesk Inventor and probably it was a time that it worked but I could not see the dialog box because it was in the background. I am not sure, but I think that could have been the consequence of running the program again on an open dialog.

Comment: Oh man, hidden/background dialogs, esp when "modal" and the app is single instance, can be really nasty :-)